# Is it possible to change values of HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar and KeyboardShrinksView at runtime in a Phonegap app?

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

In Phonegap 2.6 you can change HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar and KeyboardShrinksView in the config file and that will change the behavior for the whole app. That is ok and it is great. The question is if I can change those values after the app is running so I leave the Accesory Bar in one page and hide it the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not - the keyboard used to placed in the Cordova native code; as of Cordova 3.2.0 they moved it as a plugin where you *can* control it from JavaScript: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4935.

It is also worth bearing in mind that this plugin cannot be used with earlier versions as it potentially conflicts with the core code.